# Can't get Folder.GetDetailsOf() to return file time in seconds

Tags: windows, file, powershell, time

I'm trying to access file created time information from files on my iPhone, when it's connected to my Windows laptop. I've put together a small PowerShell test script that succesfully does so, with one small shortcoming: the function [Folder.GetDetailsOf(..., 4)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787870%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which returns the file's created time, does not include seconds… (An example output would be "18/03/2017 21:58".)

How would I get Folder.GetDetailsOf() to return seconds also?

I've tried applying a different culture (locale):

- Setting a new culture using the required time format;
- Wrapping everything in Using-Culture, as described on the [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/04/25/using-culture-culture-culture-script-scriptblock/);
- Setting the system-wide short time format (in Windows Settings => Clock, Language, and Region) to "HH:mm:ss".

None of this seems to work… However, the function [Get-Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-5.1) applies the new culture just fine. The main difference between these two functions, is that Folder.GetDetailsOf runs via a COM object (Shell.Application), whereas Get-Date does not. If using a different culture is indeed the way to go, then how could I apply them to COM objects?

## Example script

```
Function Using-Culture (
    [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]$culture = (throw “USAGE: Using-Culture -Culture culture -Script {scriptblock}”),
    [ScriptBlock]$script= (throw “USAGE: Using-Culture -Culture culture -Script {scriptblock}”)
) {
    $OldCulture = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    trap {
        [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture
    }
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
    Invoke-Command $script
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture
}

$currentThread = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo] $culture = "nl-NL"
$culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = 'HH:mm:ss'
$culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = 'HH:mm:ss'
$culture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = 'dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss'
$currentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
$currentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture

Using-Culture $culture {
    # This outputs the date in Dutch, using the format above;
    # if the format above is changed, then Get-Date's output does too
    Get-Date

    $path = 'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe'
    $shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
    $folder = Split-Path $path
    $file = Split-Path $path -Leaf
    $shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($folder)
    $shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($file)

    # GetDetailsOf() on the other hand is oblivious to the newly set culture
    $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 4)
}
```

## Why do I need this?

When copying videos off my iPhone, the files get a new Created time on my laptop, so I lose the original (actual) time. The Modified time does get copied, but it's not always correct. (Not quite sure why, this sometimes also happens when I don't do anything with the video after having shot it.)

In order to fix the Created time, I'm looking to extract the Created time from the videos *while* they're still on the phone, so I can write them to a file, and fetch them again later.

Any other suggestions on how to tackle this problem are of course also welcome :)

Comment: The title is about getting seconds from a folder, but the text is about applying PowerShell locale settings to COM objects. Please decide what your question is and make the title match the text.

Comment: Little late so you probably don't needs this anymore but I just stumbled onto this question so I will [leave this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49650833/8112776) to an answer of mine, "for the next generation", related since it shows how to retrieve folder or files times down to the millisecond using FSO in VBA (easily adapted to VBS)